Sum Function in MS Excel
[=IF(I74<=50000,"150",IF(I74<=100000,"200",IF(I74<=150000,"250",IF(I74<=200000,"300",IF(I74<=250000,"350",IF(I74<=300000,"400",IF(I74<=350000,"450",IF(I74<=400000,"500",IF(I74<=450000,"550",IF(I74<=499999,"600",IF(I74>500000,"report")))))))))))]
I have this formula in a column in MS Excel, but I could not use the SUM function at the end of the data. Please help me with this.
I was trying to have the sum of the column, but i could not get it.

The definition of the numbers are text formatting. These cannot be summed. Define the values as numbers (without quotes).

Instead of chaining if statements, have you considered using ifs which does the same thing... but a tad bit cleaner to read / write

You should really look into one of the LOOKUP functions, that expression is a monstrosity worthy of Clive Barker :-)

@Blackcat, thank you. solved with your solution

Thank you all. I am an accountant. friends, I will use the ifs or LOOKUP functions, as suggested.

Looks like you want to return 100 + 50*i where i = amount / 50000 rounded up, except if the amount is equal or higher than 500000. So you can make a really shorter formula:

Formula in column B is:
=IF(A1>=500000;"report";100+50*(ROUNDUP(A1/50000;0)))

Give it a try.
